# Pass sql data from controller to view mvc without model

Tags: sql, database, model-view-controller, view, asp.net-mvc-5

I want help with presenting data from db in a simple way, with sql, via controller code, to a view.

I can add data perfect from my view to db with this controller code:

```
`public ActionResult AddMovie()
    {
        var title = "";
        var genre = "";
        var year = "";

        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            title = Request.Form["title"];
            genre = Request.Form["genre"];
            year = Request.Form["year"];

            var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
            var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Movies (Title, Genre, Year) Values(@0, @1, @2)";
            db.Execute(insertCommand, title, genre, year);


    } return View();
}
```

`
I cant solve how my controller, select code etc, should be? (I don´t use a model).
I want to use this kind of "raw" sql.
How do i get and list my data from db, in a (.cshtml) view?

Thanks in advance!
/Adde

Comment: "I don´t use a model" Well, it's time you begin to use one ;-)

Comment: Oscar! I can get it work in other ways, with models, BUT i still want help with this issue.